# How to check if object have been saved to database

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring JDBC and I want to create a method which checks if it have been persisted to the database yet or not, meaning that would have gotten an auto incremented key.

I have a field named `id` of type int. Since primitive ints are auto assigned 0 if no other values is given I could create a method that checks if `id == 0` but then I must ensure that my primary key sequences starts on 1.

I could also create a method in the repository to check if the object was saved, however I do not want to do a query for this.

Last option that I could think of was to change the type of the `id` to `Integer` and then check if it was `null` but I don't know if that is a good way to do it.

Are there a way to have a method in the domain layer to do this?

Comment: Generally speaking using the ID (assigned at persistence to the database) seems like a good method. Have you looked into ORMs like the JPA or Spring (in your case?). This is a pretty basic feature of those frameworks and you might be spinning your wheels. Another (easy) option is have a stored procedure or auto increment on the tables so that you know a null or negative value isn't saved. Watch out for overflow!

Comment: Maybe my question was a little unclear, I updated now,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the type of `id` from `int` to `Integer` is considered a good idea: persistence frameworks such as [Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-annotations.html#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-annotations-entity) and JPA encourage it (see this example from [java.net](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/bleonard/archive/2006/12/need_a_primary.html) and this one from [adam-bien.com](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/ejb_3_persistence_jpa_for)).

Using an object type allows you to quickly tell an unpersisted object from a persisted one just by checking whether `id == null`. Just for completeness:

- `id == null`: unsaved object, perform an `INSERT`
- `id != null`: object already saved, perform an `UPDATE`

This way, you don't have to treat `0` (or any other integer value) as a special case meaning *uninitialized*; you already have `null`, which communicates nicely the idea of special case.

**Adding a business key**

An even better approach, suggested in [this article](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html), is to use a business key in additon to the database-managed ID. The business key is an entity identifier which, unlike the auto-generated primary key (*surrogate key*), has some meaning to the user (*natural key*).

You should then override the `equals` method to compare two objects using the business key, and not the auto-generated primary key.

Comment: Why is it better to use objects over primitives?

Comment: There isn't compelling arguments for using Objects over primitives unless you need a null (as answered above). Generally speaking you're dealing with a long or BigInteger for your key on large database and Integers on small databases. If you're under 0x0FFFFFFF rows then a negative can server as a null. So instead of id == null it is `if(id >= 0){ insert())}else{update()}` because the only way to get a positive ID is to insert into the database. There isn't a right answer here, but nulls and object types are an easy way to solve the problem.